# HyperLedger Composer on Fabric - console.log() doesn't work

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I currently installed the HL Composer and HL Fabric environment on docker (following the official guide https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html).

I was able to deploy successfully a bna into HL Composer.

But i'm not able to display correctly the console.log("") of transactions processor. I don't understand where is the output of the console.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output for console.log() in a TP function should be written to the chaincode container.

Use `docker ps` to see the names of the containers you have running, and then look at the log of the chaincode container.  The chaincode container will have the name of your Busniess Network and the version of Composer you are using. E.g. `docker logs dev-peer0.org1.example.com-trade-network-0.17.5`

(This assumes that you deployed your BNA to the real Fabric, not the Web profile under Playground.)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I changed the composer log level from "DEBUG" to "INFO" using the _composer network loglevel -c admin@bna_name -l "INFO" command_, in order to have a less verbose output console.